# Does the flow of water increase if it has to flow over a height and then to a depth which is more than its height?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, water

[image: Please suggest a formula also to calculate the same, if the measurements of pipe and tank are known]

Please suggest a formula also to calculate the same, if the measurements of pipe and tank are known

Answer (score 1):

[image: Syphon working principle]

If the fluid is [inviscid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow) then the outflow speed $v$ **depends only** on $h$, acc.

$$v=\sqrt{2\rho gh}$$

(If the pipe is submerged below the liquid meniscus in the receiving tank, then $h$ is the difference in height between both tanks' water levels). Where $\rho$ is the fluid's density and $g$ Earth's acceleration.

In that case there are no viscous friction losses and assuming the pipe's outlet (internal) diameter is $D$ then the volumetric throughput $Q_V$ is given by:

$$Q_V=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}v=\frac{\pi D^2\sqrt{2\rho gh}}{4}$$

So in that case the **path of flow** has no bearing on flow speed, as long as $h>0$.

But even water isn't a perfectly inviscid liquid and during flow energy losses are incurred due to viscous friction losses.

In that case it's not possible to suggest a simple *fit-for-all-conditions* formula to calculate flow speed. In the case of viscous flow, volumetric throughput will:

- decrease with increasing fluid viscosity,
- decrease with increasing pipe length,
- decrease with decreasing pipe diameter,
- decrease if local resistances such as bends, sudden constrictions/expansions, internal corrosion/surface roughness, valves or other controllers, are present in the pipe.